# FPDF import all page from document

Tags: php, fpdf

I tried to make my watermark script, it work's well if I use it on pdf with only one page. 
But when I try to use it with multi-page pdf document, it puts the watermark only the page 1. And the other pages not visible... sorry for my bad english. please help me.
This is my code:

```
$fullPathToFile = "documents/myfile.pdf";

class PDF extends PDF_Rotate {

var $_tplIdx;

function Header() {
    global $fullPathToFile;

    //Put the watermark
    $this->Image('logo.PNG', 40, 100, 100, 0, 'PNG');
    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 50);
    $this->SetTextColor(255, 192, 203);
    //$this->RotatedText(20, 230, 'Watermark text', 45);

    if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {

        $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($fullPathToFile);
        $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);
    }
    $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx, 0, 0, 200);


}

function RotatedText($x, $y, $txt, $angle) {
    //Text rotated around its origin
    $this->Rotate($angle, $x, $y);
    $this->Text($x, $y, $txt);
    $this->Rotate(0);
}

}


$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('logo.PNG', 50, 120, 120, 0, 'PNG');

$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution!:

```
if($pdf->numPages>1) {
    for($i=2;$i<=$pdf->numPages;$i++) {
        //$pdf->endPage();
        $pdf->_tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
        $pdf->AddPage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by old solution but here i am explaining how to use it.

```
    # Add 2 page
    $pdf->AddPage();  // it is required for all .
    $tplIdx2 = $pdf->importPage(2);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx2);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 5);
```

here you have to note that i am adding **$pdf->AddPage()** code that adds new page into PDF. Add Page always comes first. it is required.

**$pdf->importPage(Page_number)** import a page into current page of PDF.

there are required to import any page into the current PDF. i tried many solutions but lack of knowledge i could not use a solution of **István Maróti**.